# Regularly visited website is now partially disabled in Firefox, but works on other devices and browsers

Tags: 16.04, firefox, internet

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Firefox. I have been visiting a particular website for the last few months without a problem, but suddenly almost all the buttons and links that connect to its resources have been disabled. I can open the URL of the links if I type the full address but the problem is the web page is not loading properly.

The site loads properly on my Android phone, and it seems I am the only one having this problem because the site's support reports all OK.

I can open the site using another browser (Dillo) so the problem seems to be my Firefox. any advice?

Comment: What Firefox extensions are enabled? Sounds as if there's something which is blocking Javascript.

Comment: Give us the URL of the web site with the problem so that we can take a look at it. Does Google Chrome exhibit the same problem? Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the failing web site? Report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing Chromium from a shell prompt

```
apt-get install chromium-browser
```

when it launches after install completes, import the bookmarks from Firefox

If Chromium works well for your website, start Firefox and save your bookmarks with {Ctrl-Shift-B} to Show All Bookmarks then 
Import and Backup
Export Bookmarks to HTML
and specify a path and filename to save your bookmarks to.

Then, [reset Firefox](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/reset-firefox-howto,news-18817.html). (Many thanks to *heynnema* for reminding me of this.)

> 1. Click the menu icon; it looks like three stacked lines and is at the top right of the browser window.
> 2. Go to the end of the drop-down menu, and click on the question-mark icon.
> 3. Pick 'Troubleshooting information' in the slide-out menu.
> 4. Click on the 'Reset Firefox' button at the top right of the new Web page.
> 5. In the confirmation pop-up window, choose 'Reset Firefox'.
> 6. Import your bookmarks from {Ctrl-Shift-B}

Retry and see if the desired website is consistently accessible now.

Should that fail, uninstall Firefox from a shell prompt with

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
```

reinstall it, import your bookmarks from {Ctrl-Shift-B} and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Sounds like an awfully long way, and risky way, to prove where the problem might actually be. Maybe just try another browser, like Google Chrome. You could also just reset Firefox and not have to install/purge apps.